# How to use MeioUpload Behavior for uploading any kind of files not only images

Tags: cakephp, behavior

I would like to use the [MeioUpload Behavior](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meioupload/) for uploading any kind of documents(I want every extension to be accepted). I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246376/cakephp-meioupload-behavior) , but it didn't work for me, for some strange reason I can only upload image and pdf files for the other types of files I get this error when I attempt to submit the form : "The post could not be saved. Please, try again."

**Edit**: Well, it looks like I was finally able to upload other kind of files apart from images,I had to write the options **'allowedMime**' and **'allowedExt'** in camelCase (in the documentation they use the underscore version '**allowed_mime**', **'allowed_ext'** I don't know why:(  ), but I haven't been able to upload .zip files and most importantly I still don't know how to tell the behaviour to accept anything

```
var $actsAs = array(
    'MeioUpload' => array(
        'link_referencia' => array(
            'dir' => 'files{DS}uploads',
            'create_directory' => true,
            'allowedMime' => array('application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/rtf', 'application/zip'),
            'allowedExt' => array('.pdf', '.doc', '.ppt', '.xls', '.rtf', '.zip'),
            'default' => false,
         )
       )
    );
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It can be use for anything, hence it's called meioUpload and not meioImage

Just set the allowed file extensions and mime types when you initialiave the behavior.

Step 4 has an example http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meioupload/

Comment: @dogmatic69- I've already read that and I tried to use MeioUpload for uploading documents like PDF, DOC, XLS etc, but it dind't work :(